# How to know which variables to parametize in a large matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, parametric, matrix-equations

(dont want anyone to solve the problem, just don't understand one thing)

So I have a homework problem where I got a 3x6 matrix, and I have to parametrize the equations and solve for each variable in terms of s t and u. Theres a decent amount of zero spaces in the matrix, and it was simple to figure out what 3 variables I could choose to solve the problem.

However when I did it, I got the wrong answer. Then it occurred to me that I could have used a different 3 variables to parametrize the matrix. And doing so would get me a different answer, naturally.

Since I have to submit my homework into an online module that just compares what I input with the key, I guess there must be a way to tell WHICH variable set, specifically, I'm supposed to use.

Any ideas? Thanks, I've looked at it and I don't see how to tell.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I0KW.png

(**I don't want anyone to solve the problem** only posting because i want to give an example... I could solve by setting the X subset 1,4,5; or 1,4,6; etc as my s t and u. Doesn't seem to make a difference I can solve the problem no matter what but get different answers)

Comment: You have 5 equations in 6 unknowns. This suggests the solution will involve 1 free parameter (say t) and your 6 variables can be written in terms of that. I don't know why you want 3 free parameters or why you want to substitute values for them. Try putting $x_1 = t$ then find out the other variables in terms of t. That is your solution. The description is not unique though - you could put one of the other variables equal to t instead for example. So you might still have an upload problem.

Comment: Paul are we looking at the same picture? I have 3 equations in 6 unknowns... so there will be 3  parameters. And are you sure that there's no reason to give preference to a certain set of parametric equations?

Comment: Sorry yes, the layout threw me. So you might put $x_1 = s, x_2 = t, x_3 = u$ and work out the other variables in terms of those. You could pick any of the variables to be s, t and u though and get an equivalent set of solutions.